# how do i make fit the button inside the modal? using bootstrap

Tags: css

I have a problem, my button is not resizing or fitting in the modal, [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjSgI.png).

I have tried adding this to btn btn-primary btn-sm : style="width:60px;height:100px;"

But it didn't work, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlIM7.png).

What can i do?  What I need is the button to stay inside the modal area and still show the text. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make width:100%; instead of a fixed number. Set padding and margin accordingly, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the padding and font size of the text in the button or increase the width of your modal. I think it's better if you increase the width of your modal.

Comment: Did you try this?